# Can a C++ shared object call into a jar to send an intent?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-intent, java-native-interface

If in an android app, you have the following:

- Java code extending Activity class
- C++ shared object (calls to/from via JNI)
- Java jar lib

Can the C++ shared object call into the java jar lib and then have it send an explicit intent via Android java APIs to a separate app ?

It seems it should not work as the JNI will call directly into a method without initializing the Activity. It seems that having the java jar class extend Activity just in order to be able to send the intent is not good design anyways.

Question is:

- Is it possible to call from the shared object into the jar and send
  the intent using Activity.startActivity() ?
- Should the jar class
  extend Activity, or should the app Activity be passed in from
  somewhere?